# How to link result from one row to another on same table

Tags: mysql, sql

Hoping someone can help with the following

I have a table with 3 columns ID, Application, NextVersion

This looks like the following

```
ID1, WindowsXP, ID2,  
ID2, Windows7, ID3  
ID3, Windows8 , NULL
```

What is best way of returning my table of results as follows.

```
ID1, WindowsXP, Windows7,  
ID2, Windows7, Windows8  
ID3, Windows8 , NULL
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Submission date of your assignment ?

Comment: Study the Database Books. Something like:Introduction to databases, Abraham Silberschatz etc.,

Comment: Are these high school or college assignments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do the simple join but the second one, after some changes gives you opportunity to limit the result only to children starting with certain parent id (and all descentant). I do not know how complex your real query will be

If you only need the join then shame on you, sql basics!

```
SELECT m.id, 
       m.name, 
       y.name 
FROM   mytable AS m 
       LEFT JOIN mytable AS y 
              ON m.parent = y.id
```

and something more cpmlocated

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable 
  ( 
     id     INT, 
     name   VARCHAR(50), 
     parent INT 
  ) 
go 

INSERT INTO MyTable 
            (id, 
             name, 
             parent) 
VALUES      (1, 'WindowsXP', 2), 
            (2, 'Windows7', 3), 
            (3, 'Windows8', NULL) 
go 

WITH x 
     AS (SELECT * 
         FROM   MyTable) 
SELECT m.id, 
       m.name, 
       x.name 
FROM   MyTable as m
       LEFT JOIN x 
              ON m.parent = x.id 
go
```

Comment: Thanks Surrogate- Your example worked.
SQL basics! tell my manager who has given me SQl work with no SQL training!  I never knew you could join on the same table - do now - much appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 
t1.ID, 
t1.Application, 
t1.NextVersion,
t2.Application AS nextApplicationName
FROM
tbl_name t1
LEFT JOIN
tbl_name t2
ON( t1.NextVersion = t2.ID );
```

Comment: Thanks Manu - This needed one small amendment with left join on t2 and then works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

replace yourtable with your table name and execute this

```
  SELECT a.id, 
   a.[Application], 
   y.[Application] 
  FROM   yourtable AS a 
   LEFT JOIN yourtable AS b 
          ON a.NextVersion = b.id
```